# PHPExcel default date-format on import

Tags: php, phpexcel

when using PHPExcel to import an Excel file, i'm confused about the default behaviour of importing a date cell.
I have set the cell-formatting in the sheet to automatic:

[image]

On my computer, the regional settings are set to Dutch (Netherlands), so the date-format is set to dd-mm-yyy. I know when someone is using this sheet with other regional settings, the date is shown differently, for example: mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd.

That's all fine.
The thing is, when importing the sheet this way...

```
// PHPExcel Import Object
$PHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);

// Get Excel Data from sheet, and output to array.
$this->data = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

...the output format of the date is always: mm-dd-yy, for example: 12-31-16.

**I'm OK with that. But can I be sure that PHPExcel is always converting the date to this format? That is my actual question ;)**

Comment: Dates/Times are stored internally as MS Excel Serialized Timestamps, so internally they will always be consistent. When you render as a formatted date display, then PHPExcel will endeavour to use the number format mask defined for that cell, but it isn't locale aware

Comment: So unless I specify in PHPExcel's settings,  PHPExcel's default are mm-dd-yy ?